# The closure $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

Why the closure $\mathbb{Q}$ is not itself? Since each ball around $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ contains a point in $\mathbb{Q}$ and a point in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: But each ball around $r\in\Bbb R$ also contains a point in $\Bbb Q$. So each real number is an adherence point.

Comment: oH, RIGHT, i need to find all the points that contains a point in $\mathbb{Q}$ and a point in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. And by the way, your comment is an answer. Thanks @StefanH. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the sequence $a_n$ where $$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n!}$$ Each of $a_n$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$ but the limit of $a_n$ is $e\in \mathbb{R}\diagdown \mathbb{Q}$. So, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed, and hence $\mathbb{Q}\ne \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Answer (score 3):

There exist convergent sequences of elements in $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ which do not converge to an element in $\mathbb{Q}$. Take for example the sequence $$a_0=3, a_1=3.1,a_2=3.14,a_3=3.141,a_4=3.1415,\ldots$$ (Hopefully you can see how to generalise this method to show that every point in $\mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}$). So $\mathbb{Q}$ does not contain all of its limit points and so is not a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Only a closed subset of a metric space will be the closure of itself.

Comment: Ah, yeah, realized, a closed set contains ALL the limit points. Thank you so much Daniel!